# Reconfiguring Wordpress site

Tags: php, themes

A person in know has their hosting provider and original creator go awol and their site has been down for a bit. They had a backup of the original site but it was just a zip of the html folder.

I have been successful with getting a new host and the html folder into the new webserver but I’ve having issues display the site correctly. It appears the site was using an custom theme and although I’ve activated the theme nothing displays correctly. I’m assuming this might have something to do with pages missing but I’m not exactly sure. Any expertise or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say HTML files you mean PHP? Do you have a backup of the site's database too? Or is it actually a static export of the site generated by a caching plugin, not the actual WordPress site? (But if you say you've got the theme then you must have PHP?)

Comment: If you don't have a database backup (which this sounds like), you're screwed, Sorry to be so blunt, it might make more sense to create a new page instead of trying to manually recreate the old one. If it got some track, you can try to find it in https://web.archive.org/ and see how it looked

Comment: @Rup Correct I should be more specific. What I was given is a zip file that has just the entire html folder. In that folder has the wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes, and other .php files. I do not have a backup of the database or if I do I do not know where it is in this folder. I'm assuming it's a .db file but I haven't seen a file like that in that html folder.

Comment: All of the site's content is in the database, and if the site works at all then you must have a database connection. Maybe the settings you've got in wp-config still work from your new host. There won't automatically be a backup in the .zip: I've seen some hosts put it in the wp-content folder as a .sql export but it may not be there. Look for something .sql or with mysql in the name I'd guess. However if your database connection from wp-config does work I'd take a backup of that with mysqldump whilst you still have access.

Comment: As long as you have the original database though, and can fix up any changed URLs in it, then everything ought to just work without having to activate or deactivate plugins or themes. If you don't have the original database you'll need to get hold of it from whoever gave you the .zip. Else you've lost all of the content and settings.

Comment: @Rup thanks for the advice. It does look like I have a few promising files that could be the backup. Specifically a .gz file with db.sql in the name. When I originally restored the html folder I had to change the wp-config file to match the new database settings.